# How to add Sqlite3 gem to the Gemfile?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, sqlite

I'm a complete beginner to Rails, and I've been following a tutorial.
I got stuck when it said to type "rails server" in the blog directory. It states, "Specified 'sqlite3' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add gem 'sqlite3' to your Gemfile(and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord)."

I got ruby 2.4.4, rails 4.2.10, sqlite3 (1.4.1, 1.4.0)

I've already seen a few questions about the same problem, but the solutions didn't work for me.

I've tried :
   -gem install sqlite3
   -gem list sqlite3
   -bundle add sqlite3

Some people were talking about modifying the Gemfile.lock, changing
"sqlite3 (1.4.1)" to "sqlite3 (1.4.1-x64-mingw32)". I've also tried this, but it didn't work

Comment: share your `gemfile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following steps

1. Uninstall gem using `gem uninstall sqlite3`
2. Add following line into your Gemfile

   ```
   gem 'sqlite3', git: "https://github.com/larskanis/sqlite3-ruby", branch: "add-gemspec"
   ```
3. `bundle install`

This will fix your problem.